# JS - disable all inputs with className == "A"

Tags: javascript

On a web site I want to disable (lock) all inputs with className == "A". The inputs have multiple `classNames` like `"A B C"`:

This is the HTML

```
<input type="text" class="A B C" value="anything"/>
```

This is my JavaScript :

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT") 

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
      if (el[i].className == 'A')   
          el[i].disabled = true
}
```

But this does not work because `el.className` is always `"A B C"`. I know that I can use string methods to find `A`.

Are there more clever, faster ways ?

Info :
I need to use `document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")` and I use pure JavaScript !

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll('input.A');`, iterate over it and `disable` each element.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('A')` is what you want to use instead of getElementsByTagName

Comment: Alternatively, consider using `if(el[i].classList.contains("A"))`

Comment: `classList` would be better than `className`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 4):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` method which accepts CSS selectors:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input.A');
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on from @undefined's answer, you could use `querySelectorAll()` on the specific `class` you're looking for scoped with `input`.

**Complete code es6:**

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input.A');
inputs.forEach(input => input.disabled = true);
```

**Complete code es5:**

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input.A');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].disabled = true;
}
```